# Looking for easier equivalent tikz-code

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create figures with tikz as seen in the graphic below. The main idea is, that between two lines I sometimes want to copy nodes, which is easy. And sometimes I want to put into the horizontal space of a node on one line new nodes on another line.

So, the three nodes on the 2nd line do not exceed the horizontal space of the first `S`. Also the three nodes in the middle of the 3rd line to not exceed the horizontal space of the 2nd `S`.

Also it would be nice if I can insert horizontal rules between the lines, but I didn't do that so far.

I hoped there would be a nicer solution to create these figures. I tried with tikz-chains. I thought about tikz-trees and matrices, but couldn't think of something. I would be grateful for suggestions on how to create similar figures with less fiddling. A solution with tikz would be nice, but I also accept other ways.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{res/.style={rectangle,draw, minimum height=1.8em} }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center, node distance=8mm]
% 1st line
\node [res, minimum width=8cm] (l0s0) {$S$};
% 2nd line
\node [res, below=of l0s0.south west, anchor=west, xshift=4mm] (l1t0) {$($};
\node [res, right=of l1t0, minimum width=5cm] (l1s0) {$S$};
\node [res, right=of l1s0, node distance=2mm] (l1t1) {$)$};
% 3rd line
\node [res, below=of l1t0.south, anchor=center] (l2t0) {$($};
\node [res, below=of l1s0.south west, anchor=west, xshift=4mm] (l2t1)  {$($};
\node [res, right=of l2t1, minimum width=2cm] (l2s0) {$S$};
\node [res, right=of l2s0] (l2t2) {$)$};
\node [res, below=of l1t1.south, anchor=center] (l2t3) {$)$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, to clarify, you are looking for a simpler means within `tikz`, as opposed to an alternative to `tikz`, is that right?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I added information for your question, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not looking for an automatic or recursive solution, I think that `positioning` library is flexible enough to help you.

What I did in next code is first positioning central nodes and later positioning parenthesis nodes. I don't know if this is what you want.

Regarding to horizontal rules between lines there are several ways of drawing them. Here I've used an auxiliary `coordinate` node and intersections (`|-` or `-|`) to delimitate them.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{res/.style={rectangle,draw, minimum height=1.8em} }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center, node distance=8mm]
% 1st line
\node [res, minimum width=8cm] (l0s0) {$S$};
% 2nd line
\node [res, below=5mm of l0s0, minimum width=5cm] (l1s0) {$S$};
\node [res, left=2mm of l1s0] (l1t0) {$($};
\node [res, right=2mm of l1s0] (l1t1) {$)$};
% 3rd line
\node [res, below=5mm of l1s0, minimum width=2cm] (l2s0) {$S$};
\node [res, left= 2mm of l2s0] (l2t1) {$($};
\node [res, right=2mm of l2s0] (l2t2) {$)$};
\node [res, below=5mm of l1t0] (l2t0)  {$($};
\node [res, below=5mm of l1t1] (l2t3) {$)$};

\path (l0s0) -- (l1s0) coordinate[midway] (aux);
\draw (aux-|l0s0.west) -- (aux-|l0s0.east);

\path (l2s0) -- (l1s0) coordinate[midway] (aux);
\draw (aux-|l0s0.west) -- (aux-|l0s0.east);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you add a horizontal rule above/below the first/last line? If I use an invisible node of the same height as the others the picture gets too much height. If it is of different height the spacing is wrong.

Comment: You don't need auxiliary nodes or coordinates, something like `\draw ([yshift=2mm]l0s0.north west)--([yshift=2mm]l0s0.north east);` is enough. You can use shift with any already known coordinate.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    %\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
    \tikzset{res/.style={rectangle,draw, minimum height=1.8em} }

    \begin{document}

\xdef\Max{6}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [res,minimum width=8 cm,draw] at (0,-1) {$S$};
    % change 1.15-.15*\n in 1.20-.20*\n or more
    % if one wants 's box' dicrease faster
    \foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \w using (1.15-.15*\n)*8 ]
        in {2,...,\Max} {%

    \node [res,minimum width= \w cm,draw] at (0,-\n) {$S$};

    \foreach \i in {\n,...,\Max} {%
        \node[draw] at (\w/2+.45,-\i) {)} ;
        \node[draw] at (-\w/2-.45,-\i) {(} ;}

    }

    \foreach \i in {1,...,\Max} {%
        \draw (-4,-\i+.5) -- (4,-\i+.5) ;}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: I consider S as a non-terminal that is replaced by (S). I want that on the next line the whole replacement of S is within the horizontal boundaries set by S on the previous line. As I also consider other grammars I think your solution is too difficult to adapt. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Let's try again ;-)